# Issue with csv module in Python

Tags: python, csv, module

I'm having an issue using Python's csv module. I created a simple file in Excel containing two columns (names and ages of people) and saved it as a csv file. I then ran the following lines in Python:

```
import csv
csv_rader = csv.DictReader(open('people.csv'))
people = list(csv_reader)
```

and I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 107, in next
>       self.fieldnames
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
>       self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
>   _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Does anyone know what could be causing this, and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: try `open('test.txt',"rU")`

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks! What is the purpose of the "Ur"?

Comment: *'U' opens the file as a text file, but lines may be terminated by any of the following: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Macintosh convention '\r', or the Windows convention '\r\n'.* https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines

Comment: @BhargavRao,  the answer is  yes ;)

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents) say "If _csvfile_ is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.": Therefore I suggest you use `open('people.csv', 'rb')` even if `'rU'` seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: 'rb' does not work, it produces the same error. 'u' does the trick.

Comment: @Ryan: In that case I suspect you have a malformed csv file and would be leery of writing code that accepted it rather than flagging it as an error. Could you add the first few lines from it to your question?